# Rewrite url for accepting json data php (Request method : GET)

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, .htaccess

I am writing REST apis in php without using any framework. I am able to call apis with string data as a prameter, but problem occurs when I call a url with JSON object as parameter.

-My .htaccess file is as:

```
# Turn rewrite engine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on


# map neat URL to internal URL
RewriteRule ^get/([a-z0-9\-]+)/$    RestController.php?box=$1 [nc,qsa]

RewriteRule ^addinbox/([a-z0-9\-]+)/$   RestController.php?emailObj=$1&mode=addinbox [nc,qsa]
```

I am using jQuery for making a ajax call:

-ajax call :

```
var emailObj = {
                "name": "Mathew Murddock",
                "receiver": receiver,
                "sender": "daredevil@marvel.com",
                "subject": subject,
                "content": body,
                "time_stamp": time_stamp
            };
            var objToSend = JSON.stringify(emailObj);
            $.ajax({ 
               type: 'GET',
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               url: "http://localhost/emailServer/addinbox/",
               dataType: 'json',
               data: objToSend+'/',
               success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
               }
            });
```

But is returns this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/emailServer/addinbox/?{%22name%22:%22Mathew%20Murddock%22,…%22This%20is%20%20some%20dummy%20text.%22,%22time_stamp%22:%2212:35:0%22}/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Although I have allowed cross origin at server side:
-RestController.php

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    //Remaining code
```

The URL I am getting while ajax call is :

```
http://localhost/emailServer/addinbox/?{%22name%22:%22Mathew%20Murddock%22,%22sender%22:%22daredevil@marvel.com%22,%22subject%22:%22This%20is%20a%20mail%22,%22content%22:%22This%20is%20%20some%20dummy%20text.%22,%22time_stamp%22:%2212:35:0%22}/
```

Am I rewriting the URL in a wrong way?

Comment: remove `+'/'` fro `data: objToSend+'/'`

Comment: Did that.. Still getting the same error.


`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/emailServer/addinbox/?{%22name%22:%22Mathew%20Murddock%22,…%22:%22asdsad%22,%22content%22:%22asdsad%22,%22time_stamp%22:%2212:57:9%22}. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`


I added +'/' to format url as I have specified in .htaccess (to add '/' at the end)

Comment: jquery should have converted that to friendly url

Answer (score 1):

([a-z0-9-]+) matches lower-case letters, digits and "-" nothing else so you will not be matching your json, also consider stopping sending json in get all together. It is a bad practice
To serve the call you showed us your api should actually require a POST

Comment: I did use post.. Changed htaccess file for redirecting POST requests. Its working now thank you!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use JSON.stringify(emailObj);

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
// this line says you need to  send json file but you are sending stirng file
```

I think you don't need to use JSON.stringify or json_decode here at all. Just do:

```
data : {
            "name": "Mathew Murddock",
            "receiver": receiver,
            "sender": "daredevil@marvel.com",
            "subject": subject,
            "content": body,
            "time_stamp": time_stamp
        },
```

and in php

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
```

Pleae inform me if did not work for you?

Comment: If I do not use JSON.stringify() I was receiving data  as an array at server side. $name=`$_POST['name'];` did work..
But I needed JSON so didn't use above approach.. Thanksfor the help :)